# Shortcuts stop working when clicked out of a SearchField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement a shortcut `ctrl + f` in `ScreenA`. Screen A contains a `SearchField`; and I intend to focus to that whenever user uses shortcut `ctrl + f`.
First I tried wrapping my `Scaffold` in `FocusableActionDetector` widget like this.

```dart
// Inside build method of ScreenA
FocusableActionDetector(
  shortcuts: // shortcuts
  actions: // actions
  autofocus: true
  child: Scaffold(
     body: Column(
       children: [
         SearchBar( ...)
       ]
     )
  )
)
```

This code works only till user taps on and out of `SearchBar`. My `Scaffold` permanently looses it's focus. It starts working again when `tab` is pressed.

As per my understanding. The issue seems to be when the user taps out of the `SearchBar`; flutter moves focus to the root focus manager (I might be wrong?). So I want a way to always keep my `Scaffold` in focus so that shortcuts always work.

I have also tried wrapping entire app (`MyApp`) inside `FocusableActionDetector` and it always works. But I want my `ScreenA` to contain that functionality.

Comment: For now; I've just hacked my way by `requestfocus`ing whenever `onFocusChang` reports false (I'm using a dedicated `Focus` widget). A better approach is welcome.